# Copying text from the page and placing it in a input field when a button is clicked with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm looking to copy the text from a `<p>` element with the ID of code and put it in an input field with the data-field-id of 6197c68b4c806 when a button is clicked.

How could I do this? I would like the code to be inline if that is possible.

Comment: So add event listener, select element by id, select input, set value to text. Break task up into small parts and try to accomplish them.

Comment: How is this problem related to PHP or Wordpress? Please share more details

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access the element you want to copy the text from with:

```
`let text = document.querySelector('css selector').text` or .textContent.
```

This will save the text existing in the element.
Then you select the input, using the same technique and then do:
.value = text.
Also add an event listener to the button you want to click to trigger this:

```
document.querySelector('btn.submit').addEventListener(() => {
let text = document.querySelector('css selector').text;
document.querySelector('input#x').value = text
})
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I'm very new to this could you share a little more instate on it. sorry for the incidence.

Comment: Here in this codepen you should have everything you need:
https://codepen.io/takegabriel08/pen/BaJRgWz
Enjoy!

Comment: Hey Gabriel, wow that's grate! but maybe I didn't explain it very good. I'm looking to copy text from a <p> and place that into the input text field.

Comment: Give me a message in private and I will show you what I know

Answer (score 0):

```
       document.queryselector('#btn').addEventListener(()=>
var q_t = document.queryselector('#input').text;
document.queryselector('#output').text(q_t);
    )}
```

You have to follow this above code, hopefully you can solve this

Comment: Hey Ali Usman, I'm new to this so could you expand on this a little I really don't have any idea. Thanks!